# spring MVC hibernate crud sample application

Tags: spring, maven, spring-transactions, hibernate3

> now i am getting this error ....still i don't know how to fix
>   ....please atleast try to solve this error ...however i can't deal to
>   ahead..!!!!!!!!!
>
> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> ---
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Long
>     com.os.springjpa.controller.BookController.listPaging(BookController.java:102)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/6.0.20 logs.
>
> ---
>
> Apache Tomcat/6.0.20

Comment: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="com.os.springjpa.entity.Book"/> in the configuration. Do you have class with the above name? pls mind fqcn.

Comment: ya...sure i have it..all the classes....still it gives....

Comment: please post your web.xml and config files

Comment: above all are my configuration files.. please help me

Comment: post your "Book.java" too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can't find your entity. add this to your sessionFactory bean declaration

```
<property name="annotatedClasses">
<list>
<value>com.os.springjpa.entity.Book</value>             
</list>
</property>
```

add more values as necessary when creating more annotated entities

Comment: i tried a lot but it's not working ....still it giving nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [com.os.springjpa.entity.Book]
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.os.springjpa.entity.Book

Comment: I am unsure of what to tell you. You're sure that the package is in you classpath?